# PHP SimpleXML Namespace Problem

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to get the entry->id and entry->cap:parameter->value for every entry in the RSS feed.... below is the code I'm using.  It is displaying the id correctly however it is not displaying the value field.... please help.

```
$url = 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=1';
$cap = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($cap->entry as $entry){
    echo 'ID: ', $entry->id, "\n";
    echo 'VTEC: ', $entry->children('cap', true)->parameter->value, "\n"; 
echo "<hr>";
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you post a sample of the XML document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<value>` element is not in the same [namespace](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/XML_namespace) as `<cap:parameter>`:

```
<cap:parameter>
    <valueName>VTEC</valueName>
    <value>/O.CON.KMPX.FL.W.0012.000000T0000Z-110517T1800Z/</value>
</cap:parameter>
```

So you have to call `children()` again.

#### Code ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eqfx3o))

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=1');
foreach ($feed->entry as $entry){
    printf(
        "ID: %s\nVTEC: %s\n<hr>",
        $entry->id,
        $entry->children('cap', true)->parameter->children()->value
    );
}
```

Comment: I just tried to run this and its not printing the <value> element.  Its outputting

ID: http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=AK20110517092700FireWeatherWatch20110519060000AK.AFGRFWAFG.e64a0affe933deb186dab792161df75f VTEC:
ID: http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=AK20110517092700FireWeatherWatch20110519060000AK.AFGRFWAFG.27edc87d0c20aa820c20e6e07d509b56 .....

Comment: @Zachary it does what you asked for. See demo link.

Comment: @Gordon... it does not return the $entry->children('cap', true)->parameter->children()->value

Comment: @Zachary It returns all `/feed/entry/id` and `/feed/entry/cap:parameter/value`

Comment: @Gordon.... it does not return the /feed/entry/cap:parameter/value.... try running it!

Comment: @Zachary I **did** run it. On my machine. On the Viper codepad and I asked someone else to run it. It does return what you are asking for: http://pastebin.com/vqCC3NBR

Comment: @Gordon... my appologies... I pasted it wrong.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a hard answer to find among all the other simpleXML/namespace questions. But it was the correct one in my case. Thanks a lot.