# how to extract information about a single video - Youtube API

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api

There is an example how to search videos by search term in the documentation, but how to extract information from single video when you have the videoID.

```
<?php

  // set feed URL
    $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/LjhCEhWiKXk?v=2';

    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);


// this get the video title
$videoTitle = $sxml->title;


?>
```

I get only the video title ... also there is no views count,description and duration.

Comment: Please provide the XML you get from the API. As you can see in http://codepad.viper-7.com/MvmSNA there will be elements with duration and viewcount in the returned XML. Maybe you just have problems [accessing namespaced elements and attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027398/php-simplexml-namespace-problem/6027507#6027507)

Comment: Yes there is   <gd:rating average="4.923112" max="5" min="1" numRaters="618771" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"/>
  <yt:statistics favoriteCount="613912" viewCount="244308602"/>
  <yt:rating numDislikes="11894" numLikes="606877"/>

Comment: Note that the v2 API allows you to tailor retrieval of feeds to only contain particular elements, so to get the title, viewcount, duration and description, you can use http://codepad.viper-7.com/NLlack

Comment: Yes it shows the data I need but how to get the values ?

Comment: see the answer about namespaces I have linked above please.

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  main() [<a href='function.main'>function.main</a>]: Node no longer exists on this line $entry->children('yt', true)->statistics->children()->value
    );

Comment: I'm sure you'll figure it out. You got all the info you need now.

Answer (score 0):

This was useful for me: Visit [Use the YouTube API with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/#c9)

You have to completely parse video entry ($sxml) to get more information:

Children nodes of Entry $sxml:

```
// get nodes in media: namespace for media information
$media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
```

Get duration: ($media->children ...)

** Element yt:duration under the media:group element stores the length of the video, in seconds**

```
// get <yt:duration> node for video length
$yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
$attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
$obj->length = $attrs['seconds'];
```