# Accessing date as XML node in PHP

Tags: php, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SimpleXML Namespace Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027398/php-simplexml-namespace-problem)

I'm writing a PHP script to parse an RSS feed to a webpage.  Problem is accessing the date node.  I think that PHP is confused because `date()` is a PHP function.

```
<?php 

  $streamData = simplexml_load_file('http://www.naps.org/index.php/rss/','SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

  foreach ($streamData->channel->item as $item){
      $itemTitle = ($item->title);
      $itemLink = ($item->link);
      $itemDate = date_parse($item->date);
      $itemYear = $itemDate[year];
      $itemMonth = $itemDate[month];
      $itemDay = $itemDate[day];
      $itemOutputDate = $itemYear.'-'.$itemMonth.'-'.$itemDay;
      echo $itemOutputDate;
  }
?>
// echos...
--
--
--
--
--
```

How do I access the `$item->date` node?

EDIT

It's actually the `<dc:date>` node that I'm trying to access.

Comment: the term you want to search for is "namespace"

Comment: A blog entry on this as well: http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

Comment: I'm going to list as a favorite, thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is under the `dc` namespace which we can see points to `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/`, so for example:

```
$streamData = simplexml_load_file('http://www.naps.org/index.php/rss/','SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);


foreach ($streamData->channel->item as $item)
{
    $dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');

    $itemDate = date_parse($dc->date);
    $itemYear = $itemDate['year'];
    $itemMonth = $itemDate['month'];
    $itemDay = $itemDate['day'];

    $itemOutputDate = $itemYear.'-'.$itemMonth.'-'.$itemDay;

    echo $itemOutputDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$streamData->registerXPathNamespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
$nodes = $streamData->xpath("//item/dc:date");
```

Comment: Thanks for that alt solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is OK, then this works for me with simplexml:

(string) $item->date

Comment: try this

foreach ($streamData->channel->item as $entry){
  
  $namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);

 
  $dc = $entry->children($namespaces['dc']); 

  echo $dc->publisher;
  echo $dc->creator;

}

Comment: Thanks for that alt solution.