# php simplexml_load_file - not able to see in print_r

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am new to `simplexml parser` in PHP. I have run the examples that I have found and they work as advertised. I can't get it to work with my program though. I have searched in here for hours.

I have an XML file called core.xml (note that the node tags have colons in):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <dc:title>Lecture 3</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>John Brown &amp; Greg Smith</dc:creator>
    <cp:lastModifiedBy>Greg Smith</cp:lastModifiedBy>
    <cp:revision>165</cp:revision>
    <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2010-02-19T04:37:55Z</dcterms:created>
    <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2014-01-30T02:41:30Z</dcterms:modified>

</cp:coreProperties>
```

I use following code to load it into the parser:

```
if (file_exists('core.xml')){

    echo 'file exists <br>';
    $xml_core = simplexml_load_file('core.xml');

    print_r($xml_core);
} 
else 
{    
   exit('Failed to open core.xml.');  
}
```

The file exists but all I get at the print_r is:

```
file exists    
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

How do I access the nodes? Other XML files that I have to use are many layers in depth.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

What you describe as an error pattern in your question is actually correct behaviour and not an error.

If you use `print_r` (or `var_dump` for that matter) on a **SimpleXMLElement** it will only show you *some rudimentary information* about that object and ***not*** the entire content of the XML document.

To see the whole XML, use [the `asXML()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml) instead. Alternatively to obtain debug information you can use a library that is specifically aware on how to debug **SimpleXMLElement** content's like [**simplexml_debug**](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) written by [IMSop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop).

In your specific case, the object shows empty (no object members) because there aren't any nodes in the XML document within the default namespace (see: [*Namespaces in XML 1.0*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)) that - after the [more or less complex rules of **SimpleXMLElement** to array transitions were applied](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-i/) - would have been passed from the objects internal debug handler to the `print_r` or `var_dump` function to be displayed then. So only the class-name is given so that you can see it's an object of a certain class - and has no members:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
        ^          ^     ^ 
   object type     |     `------ object fields (empty)
                   |
             variable type
```

How to deal with that? It's very simple: Know the XML (you know it aleady) and obtain the data from it as it's documented:

- [PHP: Dealing with XML errors - Manual](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-errors) - Shows how you create (load) a **SimpleXMLElement** in a controlled manner and controlling error conditions.
- [PHP: Basic SimpleXML usage - Manual](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) - Shows how to access data inside an XML document via the API of **SimpleXMLElement**.

As your XML element names contain colons, you should be made aware that these are so called [*XML namespaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). As you've seen differences in the `print_r` output, you will also see differences in accessing the child elements within that namespace. You have to use the [`children()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children) and specify the namespace of which you would like to obtain the child elements. If you use the `xpath()` method to access elements, you need to register an namespace prefix before you use it on the **SimpleXMLElement** you call that method on.

Some assorted *selection of SimpleXML and XML Namespace related Q&A material* here on site:

- [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595946/367456) (Feb 2009)
- [PHP namespace simplexml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098170/367456) (Jan 2010)
- [PHP SimpleXML Namespace Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027398/367456) (May 2011)
- [Parse XML namespaces with php SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16412047/367456) (May 2013)

You can also obtain this information from the PHP manual, just take a look for namespace related information within the [**SimpleXMLElement** API documentation](http://php.net/book.simplexml).

Comment: a well researched answer, you get an upvote from me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` to load XML file.

Try

```
if(file_exists('core.xml'))
{
    echo 'file exists <br>';
    $xml_core = file_get_contents('core.xml');
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_core);
    print_r($xml);
}
else 
{
   exit('Failed to open core.xml.');
}
```