# PHP: SimpleXMLElement dose not parse href attributes of link tag

Tags: php

I want to parse xxm file like the below. but the result does not have any attributes include href for first "a" tag.

```
<?php
$xmlContent = <<<XML
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="Untitled-1-1.xhtml">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Untitled-1-2.xhtml"/>
        </li>
    </ol>
XML;
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);

    print_r($xml);
```

?>

Result:

```
[li] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [a] => 1
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [a] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => Untitled-1-2.xhtml
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reliably use `print_r` (or `var_dump`, etc) to inspect a SimpleXML element. The output can be missing a lot of the values. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901367/php-simplexml-load-file-not-able-to-see-in-print-r) if you want a more thorough explanation. [Other tools](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) are available for debugging these objects, if you do want a full view of them.

But just jump into the object using its API, and the values will be there. If you want the `href` value of the first link, it's here:

```
$xml->li[0]->a['href'];

// Untitled-1-1.xhtml
```

See https://3v4l.org/BOVfB

Comment: And another question, How can check the href attribute exists?!

Comment: You should just be able to use `isset` - e.g. `isset($xml->li[0]->a['href'])`